# how do i receive real time messages in React Native from Mesibo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mesibo

Need guidance about how i use mesibo with react native there is very poor documentations in the official website they just give us a examples of android and ios not for react native
please anyone guide

Comment: There's a sample React Native project within the Mesibo samples directory - https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/react-native/helloworld

Comment: I tried that but it is not working